# Insert input text data only if associated checkbox checked MySql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

here is my HTMl code actually i want to insert the input text data if only the checkbox is checked and there are 50+ input fields with unique data to insert like this HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="" method="post" name="country_form" class="form" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="Asian" name="check[0]" />
                    <label for="Asian"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Asian</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="Asian[0]" min="0" placeholder="Asian Bales">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="BabyGrow" name="check[1]" />
                    <label for="BabyGrow"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Baby Grow</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="BabyGrow[1]" min="0" placeholder="Baby Grow Bales">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="Boys_Pants" name="check[2]" />
                    <label for="Boys_Pants"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Boys Pants</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="Boys_Pants[2]" min="0" placeholder="Boys Pant Bales">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="Boys_Colour_Shirts" name="check[3]" />
                    <label for="Boys_Colour_Shirts"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Boys Colour Shirts</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="Boys_Colour_Shirts[3]" min="0" placeholder="Boys Colour Shirt Bales">
            </div>  

         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="button" value="Next" class="btn-block btn btn-lg btn-info"/>
        </div>

      </form>
     <div>
    </div>
```

Also in my Database all the input fields are in separate column
like this 
CT_ID | Asian | BabyGrow | Baby_Pants | Baby Colour Shirts  e.t.c (60 more columns)

In checkbox field Check[0] and in Input text Asian[0] array is same is that correct? How can i do this

My PHP code idea to insert or update is:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['check']); $j++) {
    if (!empty($_POST['check'][$j])) { /* CHECK IF CHECKBOX IS SELECTED */
        $q = "INSERT INTO container (Asian, BabyGrow) VALUES ('$Asian','$BabyGrow')";
        $q = mysql_query($q);
    }
}
```

but i am not sure and also it's hard to write html for 50+ div boxes with unique input fields

Answer (score 0):

take a new taste page paste below code and have an idea how many things you did wrong.1) you have not used submit button to submit n post the values.2)you have not properly named the inputs in the form. 3)logic in php code.4) have not checked whether page posted or not

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="" method="post" name="country_form" class="form" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Asian" id="Asian" name="check[0]" />
                    <label for="Asian"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Asian</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="Asian" min="0" placeholder="Asian Bales">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="BabyGrow" id="BabyGrow" name="check[1]" />
                    <label for="BabyGrow"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Baby Grow</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="BabyGrow" min="0" placeholder="Baby Grow Bales">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Boys_Pants" id="Boys_Pants" name="check[2]" />
                    <label for="Boys_Pants"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Boys Pants</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="Boys_Pants" min="0" placeholder="Boys Pant Bales">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
                <div class="squaredOne pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Boys_Colour_Shirts" id="Boys_Colour_Shirts" name="check[3]" />
                    <label for="Boys_Colour_Shirts"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="pull-left">Boys Colour Shirts</span><span class="clearfix"></span>
                <input class="bg-alert" type="number" id="bales" name="Boys_Colour_Shirts" min="0" placeholder="Boys Colour Shirt Bales">
            </div>  

         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit" class="btn-block btn btn-lg btn-info"/>
        </div>

      </form>
     <div>
    </div>
    <?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    echo "<pre>";
        $query = " INSERT INTO container (";
        $cols=$vals="";
        foreach($_REQUEST['check'] as $chkbx){
          if(isset($_REQUEST[$chkbx]) && $_REQUEST[$chkbx]!=""){
             $cols.=$chkbx.", ";
             $vals.="'".$_REQUEST[$chkbx]."', ";

          }  
        } 
       $vals=rtrim($vals,', ');
       $cols=rtrim($cols,', ');
       echo $query."<br/>".$cols." ) Values (<br/>".$vals.")";
  }

?>
```